# Authenticate WiFi client using custom database before giving access to the Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet, internet-connection, captive-portal

I want if following scenario is possible:

1. One of my employees tries to connect to our company's WiFi.
2. When he selects the SSID in available WiFi list, he is taken to a captive portal.
3. There he enters his employee ID.
4. System checks if he is online in our employee network by comparing employee ID with a IsOnline field in company's management portal's database.
5. If he is online it grants access to the Internet.

Requirement of this system is because of an automated algorithm that grants access to the Internet and other services only when employee is logged in through local company portal which is a kind of custom made HR management software. This is a Windows 7-10 supported software.

Comment: Someone please respond.

Comment: Are you asking for a piece of software that would do this?

Comment: @TheKB I just want a solution. No matter in what form it is. Whether software or manual configuration.

Comment: I have a feeling that this question would be better suited on Server Fault due to its corporate network nature. See [here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to see what is on-topic here at Super User.

Comment: @TheKB I thought server fault is more about database servers. But if you or anyone can transfer this question to server fault or I should post it there again?

Comment: I would not post it there again. Unfortunately I cannot move it there so you will have to ask a moderator to move it.

Comment: If this is a Windows network, AD and NPS cover this, with few config.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is called a [Captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) :

> A captive portal is a 'Landing' web page, presented by a Layer 3 brand
>   or Layer 2 Operator and shown to users before they gain more-broad
>   access to URL or http-based Internet services. Often used to present a
>   Landing or Log-In page, the portal intercepts observed packets until
>   such time as the user is authorized to launch browser sessions. After
>   being redirected to a web page which may require authentication,
>   payment, acceptance of EULA/acceptable use policies or other valid
>   credentials that the host and user agree to, the user is granted
>   conditional Internet access. Captive portals are used for a broad
>   range of Mobile and Pedestrian Broadband services, including Cable and
>   Commercially-provided Wi-Fi, home-hotspots and others, and can also be
>   used to provide access to Enterprise and Residential wired networks
>   (e.g. apartment houses, hotel rooms, business centers, etc.).

There are basically two ways to create one :

1. Use an enterprise-grade router that has this capability built-in
2. Use an evolved router firmware such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)

For the second option, you should install DD-WRT in a router that is in the
[DD-WRT Router Database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database). The database also contains the installation
procedure and it's best to choose a router with simple installation.
This will also required setting up in your network an internal Web server
for serving log-in credentials.

For more information, see the article :
[Create Your Own Hotspot (Using DD-WRT)](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3730746/Create-Your-Own-Hotspot-Using-DD-WRT.htm).

Comment: Actually there are some routers that provide captive portal. But I want custom authentication from my database. Not captive portal's database. Someone logged in to our site must be able to use wifi.

Comment: Many captive portals can be configured to work with custom databases and Active Directory...

Comment: The internal Web server that you provide is yours to program.

Comment: I checked dd-wrt database but unable to find any router with load balancing and multiple internet connection merging. Can you please suggest such router that also supports dd-wrt under $100?

Comment: DD-WRT itself does Multi-Homing (or Multi-WAN), with emphasis on the difference between combined bandwidth and one connection's speed. It also does [load equalization](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Dual-WAN_for_simple_round-robin_load_equalization). So you need a router supporting multiple interfaces and someone who can install and configure DD-WRT. I cannot recommend a specific router on this forum.